# SQL query with a lot of LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

I am trying to put together a query but the result is not what I expect,

```
select pii.id, pii.name, pii.sku, group_concat(pic.id) category_ids, group_concat(pimg.id) as modifier_group_ids  
from items as pii
left join category_item as pici on pii.id = pici.item_id
left join categories as pic on pici.category_id = pic.id
left join item_modifier_group as piimg on pii.id = piimg.item_id
left join modifier_groups as pimg on piimg.modifier_group_id = pimg.id
where pii.account_id = 728
group by pii.id;
```

The result is this, 4th column (category_ids) is being grouped with duplicate values..

```
id     |name                        |sku |category_ids            |modifier_group_ids |
-------|----------------------------|----|------------------------|-------------------|
336937 |Chicken Pullets             |    |12981                   |                   |
336938 |Hats                        |    |12965                   |                   |
336939 |Jack Fruit Taco Salad       |    |12975,12975,12975       |57,58,60           |
336940 |Vegatarian Taco Salad       |    |12975,12975,12975       |58,60,57           |
336941 |Pulled Pork Taco Salad      |    |12975,12975,12975       |58,57,60           |
336942 |Ground Beef Taco Salad      |    |12975,12975,12975       |60,57,58           |
336943 |Steak Taco Salad            |    |12975,12975,12975       |57,58,60           |
336944 |Chicken Taco Salad          |    |12975,12975,12975       |60,58,57           |
336945 |Jack Fruit Quesadilla       |    |12976,12976,12976,12976 |58,60,57,56        |
```

Comment: Seems like you need DISTINCT somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks fine and mostly the dups are coming along with `JOIN`. Try using `distinct` in `group_concat()` like below.

```
group_concat(distinct pic.id) category_ids,
```

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want duplicate values to be concatenated by `group_concat()`, then simply use the `distinct` keyword within the function:

```
select pii.id, pii.name, pii.sku, group_concat(DISTINCT pic.id) category_ids, group_concat(pimg.id) as modifier_group_ids  
from items as pii
left join category_item as pici on pii.id = pici.item_id
left join categories as pic on pici.category_id = pic.id
left join item_modifier_group as piimg on pii.id = piimg.item_id
left join modifier_groups as pimg on piimg.modifier_group_id = pimg.id
where pii.account_id = 728
group by pii.id;
```

Comment: thanks, this fixed the problem.. I selected the other answer because it was posted before yours.